# Oracle Provider VS 2012 RC

Tags: oracle11g, visual-studio-2012, server-explorer

**Database**: Oracle 11g

**VS 20120 Provider:** ODAC 11.2 Release 4 and Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio (11.2.0.3.0)

i just updated to VS 2012 RC and I cant even connect to my database. I dont expect EF 5 or .NET 4.5 to work with this provider but I just want to be able to set my solution target for .Net 4 and still be able to connect to my database. When I use the server explorer I do not see the provider that I usually use and the only oracle provider that comes with VS supports up to 10g and is deprecated.

**Can anyone help me with getting a provider for oracle 11g in VS 2012?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure this one out although google searches are not clear about the possibility to of finding an oracle provider for use in VS 2012 RC, .NET 4.5, using EF 5. So I will save everyone who is trying to do the same some trouble!

Devart develops providers for the different databases. I had given up on finding one for .NET 4.5 and was only looking for alternatives to the providers that oracle released for support EF 4.2. I found that alternative at Devarts site and it is called dotConnect for Oracle.

http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/download.html

At the time of writing this they are on version 7. I found out that it supports VS 2012 RC and EF5 by looking at the release notes on the right hand side of the screen. It is not made apparent anywhere else from what I can tell. It does support connecting to an oracle 11G database using .NET 4.5 and EF 5 though. Works just as it should. It costs money but I feel it is well worth the price rather then waiting for Oracle who has made no comment or announcement about developing a provider for .NET 4.5 and who never succeeded to deliver on EF 4.3 regardless.

So save yourself some time and heartache and check out dotConnect for oracle.

Answer (score 0):

This Ora.NET provider for Oracle 11g (supports .NET 4.5) is available:

64Bit
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html

32Bit
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-101290.html

Comment: I posted my answer awhile back and I agree that they do support .NET 4.5 now. I spoke with a representative on the team at Oracle who is responsible for the provider and he insured me that it would be supported along with VS 2012. The only matter was as to "when" it would be available and "what" features would be supported. The oracle provider is still limited as to what features of EF it supports.

Comment: Fair enough if it doesn't support EF fully. It's a shame that you would have to pay for something like this. I suppose it's not necessarily the Oracle end of the provider that falls short but rather the .NET end, hence a niche in the market for companies like devart to profit. You'd think Oracle would offer a free connector that makes it easier to use Oracle as a back-end to .NET and EF projects, potentially leading to more Oracle DB sales.